# CenterX Constraint animation issue

Tags: ios, swift, animation, constraints

I am trying to implement following animation for my application onboarding and it needs to be play forever and reverse back every time it finishes.

[image: Animation needs to be shown]

I designed following image to accomplish that animation.
[image: Animation Resource]
The image size is 880x335. So I wrote following code to animate the image.

```
func startAnimation(with duration: TimeInterval, afterDelay time: TimeInterval, horizontalConstantFirstPosition: CGFloat, horizontalConstantSecondPosition: CGFloat) {
    switch animationOrder {
    case .first:
        self.animatedImageViewAnimatableConstraint.constant = 110
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: time, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.animationOrder = .second
        })
    case .second:
        self.animatedImageViewAnimatableConstraint.constant = -110
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: time, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.animationOrder = .third
        })
    case .third:
        self.animatedImageViewAnimatableConstraint.constant = -330
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: time, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.animationOrder = .fourth
        })
    case .fourth:
        self.animatedImageViewAnimatableConstraint.constant = 110
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: time, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.animationOrder = .second
        })
    }
}
```

Basically, `animatedImageViewAnimatableConstraint` is the center X constraint that is initialized with 330 which is the position of first image I designed. Every time my animation method is called I changed center x anchor to the positions of value 330, 110, -110, -330 and so on. 
[image: DesignedImage2]

However, when I applied it is not animating as expected. It returns back from fourth portion of the image to first one, it is excepted to go from fourth position to second one as shown above.

[image: Wrong animation]

What should I do for the correct one, or which part is looking like wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try debugging using breakpoints?

Comment: Rather than using one single image and moving frame along why don't you use independent images and use CABasicAnimation to move image from left to right? also use CATransactions to link multiple animations and schedule them properly

Comment: isn't it going to second image. it looked likt=e

Comment: @Frankenstein I think code is running as expected because when image is in fourth position it is going to first one but I don't want to animate from most right to left. Image needs to be continued after fourth image has shown.

Comment: @jawadAli it needs to look like first gif.

Comment: @SandeepBhandari How can I do it? Should I use 3 image view or something else? Could you please give more detail or sample project?

Comment: @atalayasa: Why will you use 3 imageView? It will be single imageView, and use CABasicAnimation to move image from left to right

Comment: @SandeepBhandari There are three unique image that I need to show that's why I said but you are right it is kinda weird. I am trying to imagine what you offer but it is not so clear how to accomplish it don't you have any sample?

Comment: Ill have to write one :| lemme check if I can take sometime out to write one

Comment: I really appreciate if you can write. Because even if it is simple I have stucked :( @SandeepBhandari

Comment: @atalayasa If you have multiple images I used uicollectionview with paging enabled. I could give you a gust if you want.

Comment: @Frankenstein That's fantastic to share it. Could you please give it?

Answer (score 0):

```
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    let images = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "img1"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "img2"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "img3")]
    imageView.animationImages = images
    imageView.animationDuration = 3.0  //1 sec for each image
    imageView.animationRepeatCount = 0 //Set 0 for infinite
    imageView.startAnimating()
```

To stop just call

```
imageView.stopAnimating()
```

Comment: It is not what I am looking for. Your code only changes image view with animation there isn't any left to right animation.